# Why adding bootstrap cards to the row doesn't appear as a row but vertically?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have added cards to the row and then col-sm-3 but the cards appears in the vertical from and not as a row columns and also it appear on the right of screen not left.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let subjectState of filterSubjects">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div (click)="loadData(subjectState?.Subject.Id)" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
         <img [src]="subjectState?.Subject?.HeaderImage | fullPath" alt="Forest" class="card-img-top    float-end">
          <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title">{{subjectState?.Subject?.SubjectName | trimText: 50}}</h5>
          <h6 dir="ltr" class="card-text">{{subjectState?.Subject?.CreateDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}  </h6>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </ng-container>
```

scss

```
  .card {
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   padding: 16px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   width: 16rem;
   height: 13rem;
  }
```

I tried adding row and columns and also did the card css part but its still in vertical. How do I arrange them in row to the left?

Comment: `float-end` is a Bootstrap 5 class. Be sure you're referring to the correct documentation.

Comment: Questions like this are best addressed with rendered HTML, not application code. Please provide a sample. You can then translate the solution to your app.

Comment: Be aware that many Bootstrap elements are designed to be full-width for mobile screen sizes. Are you testing on larger screens?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems that you are creating a new row with one column `col-sm-3` for each loop over `filterSubjects`. Try moving your row **above** the loop.

Comment: even if id o that, it is in row but with spaces in between the col

Comment: @testingdevelopercrazy can you provide a repro on Stackblitz of something similar please ? I don't think I understand what you mean

Comment: @testingdevelopercrazy You can also control that spacing between the columns by adding `g-0` to `g-5` into the row (so that it reads `class="row g-*"`. Where zero is no gap at all and 5 is a larger gap.